# How to extract 1st, 3rd, 5th of group of three lines by sed or awk?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Say I have a file:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5 
Line6
Line7 
Line8 
Line9
Line10
Line11
Line12
…
```

I want to get:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line7 
Line8 
Line9
Line13
Line14
Line15
```

It means that I want the odd number of three lines (including).

I have some ideas like `for (i=1, i<=FR, i+5), {sed -n,'i, i+1p' } < input`

Could you tell me the structure of for loop in sed. And how to correct this?

Comment: So you want lines where `lineNumber mod 6 is equal to 1,2 or 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
awk 'NR % 6 == 1 || NR % 6 == 2 || NR % 6 == 3' filename.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: `awk '{n = NR % 6} 1 <= n && n <= 3'` is more concise

Comment: Still more concise: `awk '(NR-1) % 6 < 3'`

Comment: Yet another approach: `awk 'NR%6%5%4'`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
seq 20|
sed 'n;n;n;$!N;$!N;d'
```

`n` overwrites the current line with the `n`ext input line and prints the pattern space it overwrites *(unless you do `sed -n` or `sed -e'#n'`)*, so we do that three times, then we buffer two more appended input lines, and `d`elete the lot of them.

```
1
2
3
7
8
9
13
14
15
19
20
```

The other thing I had was like this:

```
sed -ne:p -e'$p;N;s/\n/&/2p;tn' -ebp \
     -e:n -en \
     -e:d -e'N;s/\n/&/2;t'      -ebd
```

Which will first buffer two appended `N`ext input lines and count the `\n`ewlines added and print if the current line is the last or if the buffer is full, then overwrite that w/ the `n`ext input line, and buffer two more before deleting those as well.

It might also be written:

```
sed -ne:p -e'$p;N;s/\n/&/2p;tn' \
     -ebp -e:n -e'n;n;n'
```

But the advantage to the `t`ests is that you can easily parameterize it like:

```
altl(){ sed -ne":t$(n=0 nt='\n\t' b=$nt\b
        while   [ "$#" -gt "$((!(n+=1)))" ]  &&
                c=${1%?}        p=${1##*[!p]} \
                l=$nt${p:+\$p;} p=$nt$p${p:+;}n
        do      case    $1      in
                (''|0*|*[!0-9]*?|*[!pd])
                   >&2  printf '"%s":\tARG ERR\n' "$1"
                        kill -2 0;;
                (1?|?|$((c-=1))) ! :; esac         &&
                printf  "\n:$n.0${l}N;%s$c;t$n.1%b" \
                        's/\n/&/' "$b$n.0\n:$n.1"
                shift;  printf %b "$p${1+\c}${nt}bt"
        done)"
}
```

It wouldn't be terribly difficult to do the other either, actually: you'd just just have to print so many `[Nn]`s at a `sed` to make it happen. So maybe I wasted my time writing the above. But it does work:

```sh
(   set -x
    seq 150 |
    altl p 40d p p 10d 5p
)
```

---

```
### This is the sed script the function's shell loop writes.
### We see it because I enabled -xtrace output on stderr.

:t
    p;n
:2.0
    N;s/\n/&/39;t2.1
    b2.0
:2.1
    n
    p;n
    p;n
:5.0
    N;s/\n/&/9;t5.1
    b5.0
:5.1
    n
:6.0
    $p;N;s/\n/&/4;t6.1
    b6.0
:6.1
    p;n
    bt

### This ends the sed script.
### The rest is sed's stdout.
```

---

```
1
42
43
54
55
56
57
58
59
100
101
112
113
114
115
116
117
```

Comment: Thanks! could you give me a few explanations?

Comment: `sed 'N;N;p;N;N;N;d'` is *almost* the same, but won't print a partial last group.

Comment: @glennjackman - you can make it - but you have to use `n` for the lines you want to print, only buffer the deleted ones w/ `N`. Honestly, I should have gone there first *(and did, actually, when I thought it was just every other - my first answer was `sed n\;d`)*, but then I did something I've been doing a lot lately. Sometimes you just get in a rut.

Comment: With GNU sed, you could maybe use the *first~last* address notation e.g. `sed -n '1~6 {N;N;p;}'`

Comment: Another solution with GNU sed: `sed '4~6d; 5~6d; 6~6d'`.

Comment: @lcd047 - but why not just `n;n;n;N;N;d`? It's even easier to do - and it works for all of the `sed`s.

Comment: Because some of the `n` might fail near the end of file.  Case in point: look at the difference between `seq 20 | sed '4~6d; 5~6d; 6~6d'` and `seq 20 | sed -n '1~6 {N; N; p;}'`.

Comment: @lcd047 - the `N`s might fail *(in GNU `sed`)*, and so you might need `$!N;$!N` - and that's it. The `n`s don't fail.

Comment: @lcd047 - well, yeah, those are lumped. Run `sed 'n;n;n;$!N;$!N;d'` against it. With that function i wrote here you could just do `altl 3p 3d`.

Comment: Then you do `seq 23 | sed 'n;n;n;N;N;d'` vs. `seq 23 | sed '4~6d; 5~6d; 6~6d'`, and you find out you need a different special case. :)

Comment: @lcd047 - no you don't - need a POSIX `sed`. But if you just put `$!N;$!N;d` to handle GNU's breaking w/ the standard it will work.